# The code upon running says Data cardinality is ambiguous

Tags: python, tensorflow

The code upon running says Data cardinality is ambiguous:   x sizes: 2298   y sizes: 287 Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.
Can you please help me with this?

```
import tensorflow as tf
input_size=10
output_size=2
hidden_layer_size=50
model=tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_layer_size,activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_layer_size,activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(output_size,activation='softmax')
    ])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
batch_size=100
max_epochs=100
model.fit(train_inputs, train_targets,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=max_epochs,
          validation_data=(validation_inputs,validation_targets),
          verbose=2)
```

Comment: The problem is with your data shapes, not with the model code. Include the shape of `train_inputs` and `train_targets`

Comment: What is the shape of `train_inputs`, `train_targets`, `validation_inputs`, `validation_targets` ?

Comment: 1. You didn't specify input size in your model. In the first layer specify ``input_shape`` argument. 2. Tell us about your data shape. Add your x and y shapes to your question. 3. Specify which line lead to error. Attach Stack trace error to your question.

Comment: @paradocslover the shape of train_inputs is (2298,10) and train_targets is (2298,)